# What does "[IN-USE] account is locked by another session or for maintenance, try again." mean?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I'm in the process of migrating a computer from Windows To Ubuntu.  I followed [these instructions](http://fosswire.com/post/2008/03/migrate-your-thunderbird-emails-from-windows-to-linux/) to move my Thunderbird emails over.  The emails that I moved show up, but when I try to check for new emails I get this message:

> Sending of password did not succeed. Mail server pop.windstream.net responded:
>
> [IN-USE] account is locked by another session or for maintenance, try again.

I click OK and another box pops up saying:

> Login to server pop.windstream.net failed.

With 3 options:

- "Enter new password" (I'm **SURE** the one I'm typing is correct)
- "Cancel"
- "Retry"

I've tried all 3.  Retyping my password, clicking "Retry", same result.

While I was typing this, I got a toast that said:

> Thunderbird's attempt to connect to pop.windstream.net has timed out.

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for my migration was a virus on the Windows machine.  As it turns out, the virus was automatically sending email.  A pop server can only handle one client at a time so I was prevented from accessing the account on another machine.  Unplugging the infected machine's internet cord solved the problem.